# Python, Draw a circle with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am looking for a command that will draw a circle on an existing image with PIL.

```
im = Image.open(path)
```

I want a function that will draw a colored circle with radius `r` and center `(x,y)`

Answer (score 33):

```
image = Image.open("x.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
leftUpPoint = (x-r, y-r)
rightDownPoint = (x+r, y+r)
twoPointList = [leftUpPoint, rightDownPoint]
draw.ellipse(twoPointList, fill=(255,0,0,255))
```

refer official doc: [PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse(xy, fill=None, outline=None, width=0)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse)

Comment: `ellipse()` takes a bounding box (i.e. two sets of X/Y coordinates), not a set of X/Y coordinates and a pair of diameters.

Answer (score 10):

Use [ImageDraw.ellipse](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse) with square bbox like (0,0,10,10), which mean with diameter 10.

Answer (score 9):

```
image = Image.open("x.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r), fill=(255,0,0,0))
```

> using this way i am unable to make it translucent, it is always opaque

This problem can be solved by the solution given here:
[How do you draw transparent polygons with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359706/how-do-you-draw-transparent-polygons-with-python)

Direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21768191

Answer (score 5):

```
image = Image.open("x.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r), fill=(255,0,0,0))
```

using this way i am unable to make it translucent, it is always opaque